# repository in grandle.properties instead in build.gradle

Tags: gradle

is it possible put the repositories configuration in {gradle_home_user}/gradle.properties instead in {project}/build.gradle?

Something like this:

build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "maven_url"
        credentials {
            username = "user"
            password = "password"
        }
    }
}
```

gradle.properties

```
repositories.maven.url=maven_url
repositories.maven.credentials.username=user
repositories.maven.credentials.password =password
```

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. Have You tried?

Comment: I tried and it does not seems to work. All the above `repositories*` properties were added as gradle properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But the property names with dots will need to be accessed using the following notation `${project["my.prop.name"]}`. Instead I would recommend using underscores for property separators instead. These can be accessed simply by using `${my_prop_name}`.

**build.gradle**

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "${repositories_maven_url}"
        credentials {
            username = "${repositories_maven_credentials_username}"
            password = "${repositories_maven_credentials_password}"
        }
    }
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
repositories_maven_url=maven_url
repositories_maven_credentials_username=user
repositories_maven_credentials_password=password
```

Comment: I don't want to write in all my project's build.gradle the repositories part, so i don't want use placeholders.

Comment: You can inject the common configuration from the root project using the `allprojects` or `subprojects` closures in the root project's `build.gradle` file. It is described in detail [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)